# XAML Table with sorting by column clicking in C++ UWP App - design and binding problems

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm just beginning to build a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) C++ app using VS2015. I've worked in Android before and in .NET, but not UWP (and before you suggest using .NET, I'm using this as a project to get more C++ experience). I'm trying to add a screen to the app that will basically have a table with data that can be sorted by clicking on the corresponding column (one click for ascending, another to reverse. Click a different column header to sort by it instead).

Searching for help on this is a mass of craziness however. Half of the results recommend gridview but when I try to implement them parts of gridview turn out to be unavailable in the UWP platform and I can't seem to make it clickable. Others recommend listview but I want to have multiple columns that get sorted together on clicking of one, and keeping them in sync seems like it could get complicated. There are a variety of other options but I'm getting lost in the mix, particularly when some are then unavailable for UWP and MSFT seems to often have out of date documentation.

I'm also new to this XAML/binding approach and a bit lost with it. With an Android app version of this application I had an sqlite database from which I pulled a table that could be displayed to the screen. I was planning on a similar approach here but in that case what do I bind to? Do I query the database, build a table in memory, and then bind to that? That seems clunky and problematic if columns have different data types. And if gridview doesn't work, in what do I then display it?

That's a kind of vague and wide question I know, but this seems to be one of those instances where further research makes me more lost rather than bringing clarity so after a few hours of searching I thought I'd just ask for advice. This seems like it should be such a simple task that I must be doing something wrong. Any recommendations you have are most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Control as you said in UWP.

Also it seems the data grid control to display data in a table is that you want. Please refer the DataGrid in this link: https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid. When we click the corresponding column the column can be changed.

We should be able to bind the date to the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` and set the head name to `DataGridTextColumn`.

There is a sample for it, you should be able to see it in https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/tree/master/src/SampleUwpApp.